# Going to India. Want to bring 4-5 powerbooks, 2 ipads, 2 iphones all 2+ y.o. to give to friends & donate, PLUS I'll bring mine. Any duty exemptions?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, gifts

Going to India. Want to bring 4-5 powerbooks, 2 ipads, 3 iphones all 2+ y.o. to give to friends & donate, PLUS I'll bring mine. Any duty exemptions???

Comment: From where are you going to India?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [exemption](https://old.cbic.gov.in/resources//htdocs-cbec/customs/cst2023-010223/G.E.-140.pdf) from customs duty for used computer equipment imported and donated to various types of organizations (schools, libraries, etc.), which may actually be useful to you assuming you actually want to donate the electronics rather than just give them to your friends. You would have to arrange with the organization for them to pick up the electronics at the airport directly.

Comment: Thank you. I did want to do both. I'll research a charity--preferably orphaned kids school. Even if I only pay for friends - one-third of items - it will save me duty and they will be used.